# Calling a python decorator with args directly (i.e. not wrapping another function)

Tags: python, python-decorators, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have a decorator which itself can take arguments, something like this:

```py
def my_decorator_with_args(decorator_arg):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            # some arbitrary logic using the decorator_arg(s)
            if decorator_arg == 100:
                print(f'Not running {func}')

            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return decorator
```

and some function to be decorated, e.g.

```py
def add(x,y): 
    return x + y
```

And I want to call `my_decorator_with_args` directly as a higher-order function rather than decorating a function with it, I know that I can do the following:

```py
from functools import partial 
p = partial(add, 1,2)
```

```sh
In [50]:z = my_decorator_with_args(100)(p)()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[50]: Not running functools.partial(<function add at 0x10db7a290>, 1, 2)

In [51]: z = my_decorator_with_args(99)(p)()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [52]: z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[52]: 3
```

But is there a more elegant/readable way of acheiving this?

Comment: This has to be discussed case by case. For this one, if you hate parentheses, you could decorate raw ``add`` by ``@`` first and then call partial.

Comment: sorry, do you mean when `add` is defined (i.e. the standard decorating syntax at the top of the function definition)?  That's the point of the question, I can't do that as the value which is passed into the decorator is only known at runtime (`decorator_arg` in the example above).

Comment: Sounds like you want to dynamically update your ``inner`` function. Even there is a way to make it more readable in format by using normal function call at the end, like ``foo()``, then it will be easy to confused which ``decorator_arg`` was used to decorate ``foo``. Maybe you want add ``decorator_arg`` as a argument of ``inner``.